# Can't deserialize JSon to C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I have the following JSon returned in my windows forms app .net 4, but i can get the Avatar URLs! attempts either yield a null value or in my current attempt below an unexpected character

Here is the JSon:

```
{"self":"http://jira.prod.xxxxxx.com/rest/api/2/user?username=firstname.lastname","key":"zzzzzz","name":"firstname.lastname","emailAddress":"firstname.lastname@xxxxxxxxxx.com","avatarUrls":{"16x16":"http://jira.prod.xxxxxx.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=zzzzzz&avatarId=12500","24x24":"http://jira.prod.xxxxxx.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=zzzzzz&avatarId=12500","32x32":"http://jira.prod.xxxxxx.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=zzzzzz&avatarId=12500","48x48":"http://jira.prod.xxxxxx.com/secure/useravatar?ownerId=zzzzzz&avatarId=12500"},"displayName":"Lastname, FirstName","active":true,"timeZone":"Europe/Dublin","locale":"en_UK","groups":{"size":1,"items":[]},"applicationRoles":{"size":1,"items":[]},"expand":"groups,applicationRoles"}
```

and here is my current attempt to get the URLs, the above json is passed in "result":
I'm using Newtonsoft JSON library

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myselfResponse>(result);

 public class myselfResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("emailAddress")]
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }

    //public AvatarUrls avatarUrls { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("avatarUrls")]
    public string avatarUrls { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls
{
    public string _16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
}
```

the error i get is unexpected character

Any help would be great thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have commented out the correct property of type `AvatarUrls` and replaced it with a string property. Don't do that.

And as you've already discovered you can set the property names for JSON properties to anything with the `JsonProperty` attribute. So, uncomment that line, remove the extra string property, and do this to your "invalid name" properties:

```
[JsonProperty("16x16")]
public string Size16x16 { get; set; }
```

Or if you'd prefer it to be dynamic don't use a separate object at all and do this:

```
[JsonProperty("avatarUrls")]
public Dictionary<string, string> AvatarUrls { get; set;}
```

Note that by using `JsonProperty` you can also use correct naming in C# and capitalize property names.